# nuxt error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" when deploying in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

After deploying my application (SPA so CSR) on my production server (after having yarn run build)

from the first page and the other pages (entry point /) I get the following error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

pointing directly to the first < of the <!doctype html>

My environment :

Node version: 14.10.1
Version of nuxt :

package.json

```
{
  "name": "secret-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --dotenv .env.dev",
    "build": "nuxt build --dotenv .env.prod",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/utils": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@ryanburnette/vue-closable": "^1.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
    "vue-clipboard": "^0.0.1",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-slider-component": "^3.2.14",
    "vue-toast-notification": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "^5.0.0-1624817847.21691f1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  theme: 'basic',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s',
    title: '',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'fr'
    },
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: {
    color: '#000'
  },
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/default.css",
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/detector.client.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-packages.client.js',
    '~/plugins/axios-catcher.client.js'
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  pwa: {
    icon: false,
    manifest: false,
    meta: {
      name: undefined,
      description: undefined,
      ogType: undefined,
      ogSiteName: false,
      ogTitle: false,
      ogDescription: false,
      mobileApp: false,
      mobileAppIOS: undefined,
      appleStatusBarStyle: undefined,
      ogImage: false,
      ogHost: false,
      ogUrl: false,
      nativeUI: false,
      favicon: undefined,
      icons: undefined
    },
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth'],
    fallback: true
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelJWT': {
        provider: 'laravel/jwt',
        url: process.env.API_URL,
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60
        },
        refreshToken: {
          maxAge: 20160 * 60
        },
      },
    }
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

apache2 vhost config from production server :

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/secret/dist

    <Directory /var/www/secret/dist>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Do you know how to fix this problem? Am I missing something?
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a Github link for this one? Does it work locally?

Comment: It works perfectly localy when i test it with : yarn run start I have this problem only on my production server but I confess I do not understand. I can't give you direct access to the code, it's a private project done in a professional context. Thanks for your help

Comment: It should be `yarn start` (it's `npm run start` tho). Also, if it is working properly it's not a Nuxt issue IMO. Did you try to launch your app on Heroku for debugging purposes? I'm not an Nginx pro but I think the issue comes from here. On Heroku, you will not need to deal with this kind of thing. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, it's actually the rewrite rules in the vhost that don't work properly. By creating a .htaccess directly at the root of my application with this configuration it works correctly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Firebase modify firebase.json from**

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**to**

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "server"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```